# Find the minimum value of the expression $\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x^4+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}y^4+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}z^4+1}$

Tags: calculus

Let $x, y, z$ be positive real numbers such that $x + y + z = xyz$.

Find the **minimum value** of the expression $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x^4+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}y^4+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}z^4+1}$$

My attempt:
By using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and AM-GM inequality,
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}t^4+1}\cdot\sqrt{3+1}\geq t^2+1$$
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x+y+z)\geq3(xyz)^{\frac{2}{3}}\cdot 3(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}=9xyz$$
$$\therefore \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x^4+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}y^4+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}z^4+1}\geq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)+\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}\left (\frac{9xyz}{x+y+z}+\frac{3}{2} \right)=6$$
with equality if and only if $x=y=z=\sqrt{3}$

What are the **alternative methods** to solve this question?

Comment: For what I see, it seems that the method you propose just gives an inequality, not the minimum. Maybe you should explain more in detail. Moreover: is there any reason why the Lagrange multiplier method cannot be applied?

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli The answer proposed is complete, as the inequality is not just a lower bound, $6$ can be achieved by the choice of $x=y=z=\sqrt3$, hence that's indeed the global minimum under the constraints given. In fact while alternate methods including Lagrange multipliers exist, arguably they'll take more effort in finding and establishing the minimum.

Comment: @Macavity: I have put at denominator $0.1^2+1$ instead of $0.1^2-1$. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a good method, here is an alternative with only AM-GM. First, we have
$xyz = x+y+z \geqslant 3\sqrt[3]{xyz}\implies xyz \geqslant 3\sqrt3$.  Further, again using AM-GM,

$$\sqrt{\frac{t^4}9+\frac{t^4}9+\frac{t^4}9+1}\geqslant \sqrt{\frac4{3\sqrt3}t^3}=\frac2{3^{3/4}}t^{3/2}$$

$\begin{align}
\implies \sqrt{\frac13x^4+1}+\sqrt{\frac13y^4+1}+\sqrt{\frac13z^4+1} &\geqslant \frac2{3^{3/4}}(x^{3/2}+y^{3/2}+z^{3/2}) 
\\ &\geqslant \frac2{3^{3/4}}\cdot 3\,(xyz)^{1/2} 
\\ &\geqslant \frac6{3^{3/4}}\,(3\sqrt3)^{1/2}=6
\end{align}
$

with equality possible iff $x=y=z=\sqrt3$, so we have the minimum.

---

P.S. Yet another way would be to show the estimate $\sqrt{t^4/3+1} \geqslant \sqrt3 t -1$ holds, and then $\sum \sqrt{x^4/3+1} \geqslant \sqrt3(\sum x)-3 = \sqrt3(xyz)-3  \geqslant \sqrt3\cdot 3\sqrt3-3 = 6$

Answer (score 2):

Your method is very straightforward. I am going just to post another approach that may contain a new idea.

Firstly;
$$xyz=x+y+z\ge 3 \sqrt[3] {xyz}\implies (xyz)^3\ge 27xyz\implies x+y+z=xyz\ge 3\sqrt3.$$

Secondly, a simple computation shows that $f(t)=\sqrt{\frac {t^4}{3}+1}$ is a convex function. Therefore, by Jensen's inequality, we get:

$$\sqrt{\frac {x^4}{3}+1}+\sqrt{\frac {y^4}{3}+1}+\sqrt{\frac {z^4}{3}+1}\ge 3\sqrt {\frac {(\frac {x+y+z}{3})^4}{3}+1}\ge 3\sqrt {\frac {(\frac {3\sqrt 3}{3})^4}{3}+1}=6. $$

More information about Jensen's inequality is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).